# Substring or regex match in nspredicate collection key path

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I'd like to use NSPredicateEditor to provide the user with the ability to create custom filters with complex boolean logic.

The problem is that the data being filtered is a single object of type `RowData`  and the user would like know if it contains a collection containing a component whose title matches a pattern:

```
class RowData {
  let collections: [Collection]  
}
class Collection {
  let components: [Component]
}
class Component {
  let title: String
}
```

NSPredicate won't let me use a LIKE operator for the keypath collections.components.title (because title, in that context, is an array of Strings), only CONTAINS, which doesn't do what I need.

Is there any way to use NSPredicate/NSPredicateEditor for this, or will I have to roll my own?

Comment: Did you try to create a row template in code?

Comment: I haven't done anything with NSPredicateEditor yet. Right now I'm hardcoding NSPredicate rules to test out all the functionality I want. I assume if I can't manually make an NSPredicate to do this, NSPredicateEditor can't, either

Comment: Does "ANY collections.@distinctUnionOfSets.components.title LIKE %@" work?

Comment: "`[General] *** -[NSMutableSet unionSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet`"

Comment: Sorry, too much Core Data. Try "ANY collections.@distinctUnionOfArrays.components.title LIKE %@".

Comment: That worked! I had no idea about [KVC Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html). Thanks!